# merging master to develop then cleaning master

Tags: git, git-flow, git-tower

I am very new to git.

Not so long ago I learnt about GitFlow, and I'd like to utilize it, however I have already got a long commit history in my master branch.

Can I move everything over to develop, so I'll get the whole history, and commiting only my latest release to master?

I am using Tower on my mac, but I am happy to use command line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a `develop` branch yet, you can simply create one at the right point of `master`:

```
git checkout -b develop master~1
```

That way, the last commit of `master` is in `master` only, all the other commits are part of the new `develop` branch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have a develop branch already. Would this work either way, if I leave out the `-b` flag? I would like to learn the meaning of this `master~1`.

Comment: @BenS In that case, it is best to merge `master` to `develop` (or `master~n` to `develop`, if you don't want to integrate the last n commits of `master`)